# Deep Promise.all

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a promise chain that ends with saving a list of files. I want to wait until all the files save or fail, then proceed with my chain. The issue is that when I use `Promise.all` on a list of promises that have their own sub-chains, the `then`s on the `Promise.all` start to resolve before the `then`s on the promises within the `Promise.all`. See the commented example below.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
// Make a promise out of the file write function
const promiseWriteFile = (file, data, options) => {
    return util.promisify(fs.writeFile).call(fs, file, data, options);
};

...

console.log('Received files');
console.group();
// Start long promise chain
somePromise(...)
    .then((result) => {
        console.log('validating blah blah');
    })
    .then((result) => {
        ...
    })
    .then((result) => {
        // Now I need to save the files to the disk
        let path = './uploaded_files/';
        // Here I want to resolve all the file save promises, or find one that fails
        return Promise.all(
            request.files.map((file) => {
                let filename = path + Date.now() + '_' + file.originalname;
                // Purposely change `path` so that the next file write will fail
                path = './garbage/';
                console.log('Trying to save file:', filename);
                return promiseWriteFile(filename, file.buffer, 'binary')
                    .then(() => {
                        console.log('Saving file:', filename);
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log('Could not save file:', filename);
                        throw error;
                    });
            }),
        );
    })
    .then(() => { // <======= I don't want this to happen until the promises in the `Promise.all` above have fully, DEEPLY resolved
        // set success message
        message = 'Part successfully created.';
        console.groupEnd();
        console.log('Part created successfully.');
    })
    .catch((exception) => {
        message = exception.message;
        console.groupEnd();
        console.log('Part invalid.');
    });
```

The output looks like:

```
Received files
  validating blah blah
  Trying to save file: ./uploaded_files/A.txt
  Trying to save file: ./garbage/B.txt
Part invalid.
Could not save file: ./garbage/B.txt
Saving file: ./uploaded_files/A.txt
```

So as you can see, the lines that print "Could not save file" and "Saving file" execute AFTER the then/catch of the big promise chain. You can tell because `console.groupEnd()` gets called first and then there is further output.

How can I make sure the then/catch on the big promise chain doesn't happen until all the sub-promises are completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're re throwing the error in your catch block on the `map`

```js
.catch((error) => {
  console.log('Could not save file:', filename);
  throw error;
});
```

This is breaking your `Promise.all()` and causing it to catch in its chain before completing all promises. You should instead just be forwarding that error along instead of crashing the error chain. You need to rethink how you want to confirm all of the writes and the following steps.

An example of processing the returns later:

```js
    .then((result) => {
        let path = './uploaded_files/';
        return Promise.all(
            request.files.map((file) => {
                let filename = path + Date.now() + '_' + file.originalname;
                path = './garbage/';
                console.log('Trying to save file:', filename);
                return promiseWriteFile(filename, file.buffer, 'binary')
                    .then(() => {
                        return  { filename };
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        return { error, filename };
                    });
            }),
        );
    })
    .then((results) => {
        const successes = results.filter(({ error }) => !error);
        const failures = results.filter(({ error }) => error);
        // process them here
    })
```

Now you can process them how you want, and each object has a filename in the return, letting you identify them, remove them, whatever you want with them.

Comment: So the problem is using the actual `throw` here. Throwing the error immediately breaks out of the big promise chain, killing the promise.all and brings me into the bottom-most catch block, but leaves the unresolved promises still running. Is that accurate? I'm not sure how I would forward the error then, without throwing it. Would it be more appropriate to use `Promise.allSettled` and then run through the list to look for errors?

Comment: Nah, just take all of the promises and return an object with a message or an error. Then process all of the returns later. IF this is mission-critical and it must be an all or nothing, at that point you can then also remove the successful files at that point. Remember the return of a promise is anything you want it to be, and a Promise.all resolves to an array. Arrays of homogenous objects with keys message or error are easily processed with filters, maps, etc.

Comment: `Promise.all().then((arrayOfReturns) => {...})` is the pattern you'd want to look into.

Comment: thank you, I think that will work and I will try it now

Comment: @nullromo updated the answer with an example of how you can do it.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Good to keep in mind this pattern of returning results, then handling errors when I want everything to resolve before moving on.

Answer (score -2):

When you use .catch on a promise.all it is going to add the catch for each sub promise you have added. There is not a "catchFinally" method.

To stop other promises from happening take a look at this example:

```
Promise.config({ cancellation: true }); // <-- enables this non-standard feature

const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'resolve1');
}).then(a => { console.log('then1'); return a; });

const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(reject, 2000, 'reject2');
}).then(a => { console.log('then2'); return a; });

const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 3000, 'resolve3');
}).then(a => { console.log('then3'); return a; });

const promises = [promise1, promise2, promise3];

Promise.all(promises)
    .then(values => { 
        console.log('then', values); 
    })
    .catch(err => { 
        console.log('catch', err); 
        promises.forEach(p => p.cancel()); // <--- Does not work with standard promises
    });
```

Note that even though promise3 is cancelled, its setTimeout callback will still be called. But it will not trigger the then or catch callbacks. It will be as if that promise never comes to a resolution ... ever.

Comment: I would suggest not using the cancelation of Promises as it can leave the system in an unknown and possibly unstable state

Comment: @RobertMennell i would disagree. If he has promises that are dependent on the successful completion of past promises then canceling the next promises makes sense.

Comment: @RobertMennell please provide more information on "leaving the system in an unknown state". If he knows his application may have an unknown state, then he should handle these conditions outside of the promises as well.

Comment: They should be handling it in a serial manner if it's all or nothing. Otherwise, they are writing files to disk before they should be. If this is supposed to be an all or nothing method then you want to write the files one at a time, if any fail you want to remove the artifacts of the successful writes, and then you want to log.

By canceling promise chains you could have already written the file to disk, and only canceled the .next() step and the log. The file could still already be there.